# Problem with Natbib after installing biblatex

Tags: natbib

I installed BibLaTeX, and I couldn't get it to work so I decided to go back to my old BibTeX `natbib` - but now I can't get my references back.
What's going on...? Do I have to redo the installation of BibLaTeX?

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[sort]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{References}\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Have you removed the auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, ...) ? It is a typical problem when one switch from one bibliography style to a different one. By the way, using `\thispagestyle{empty}` after `\bibliography` might not produce the right results (if the bibliography spans over two or more pages) since it is executed at the end of the bibliography.

Comment: Are you actually seeking \pagestyle{empty} BEFORE the bibliography command? Have you tried compiling several times?